# galaxy s3 not detected as media device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Using Galaxy S3 GT-i9300 and it is not detected as media storage device on my laptop.I have installed the latest version of Samsung USB drivers too.Strangely it does detect on my office laptop running on older version of windows xp.
Please help me out people

Comment: Have you tried on newer Windows versions, or at least XP service pack 3? sounds funny an OS should support a driver that was written years later

Answer (score 0):

What is your laptop running for OS? Is your phone unlocked when you plug it in?

I've had to reinstall USB port drivers on my laptop before. Follow these instructions:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817900

Comment: Try to quote the instructions here, rather than just linking to a website.